# why coredump when i use curl and hmac together?

Tags: libcurl, hmac

when i use hmac and curl then the programe coredump. And the log run there

```
"Oct 17 17:58:37 info [6382]: 6385 httpsPost before apped headers"
```

I got the infomation in gdb

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0819a8e7 in EVP_MD_CTX_md ()
(gdb) where
#0  0x0819a8e7 in EVP_MD_CTX_md ()
Cannot access memory at address 0x4004
```

these information is no help to me,is anyone know about it?

but when I delete the code:

```
HMAC_CTX ctx;
HMAC_CTX_init(&ctx);
HMAC_Init_ex(&ctx, AUTH_KEY, strlen(AUTH_KEY), EVP_sha256(), NULL);
HMAC_Update(&ctx, (unsigned char*)&szJsonData, strlen(szJsonData));
HMAC_Final(&ctx, result, &len);
HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
```

it run well,I don't know why

I got these information :

- successfully set certificate verify locations:
- CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs

  void postHttps(uint32_t uid,std::map& headResult,std::map& bodyResult)
  {

  ```
  char szJsonData[1024];
  memset(szJsonData, 0, sizeof(szJsonData));
  std::ostringstream requetContent;
  requetContent<<"{\"cmuid\":\""<<uid<<"\",\"s\":2}";

  strcpy(szJsonData, requetContent.str().c_str());

  char bodyBuff[1024];
  memset(bodyBuff, 0, sizeof(bodyBuff));

  char headBuff[1024];
  memset(headBuff, 0, sizeof(headBuff));
  uint32_t start = sox::env::now;
  uint32_t ssend = sox::env::now;


  unsigned char* result;
  char sign[1024] = {0};
  unsigned int len = 256;
  result = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
  log(Info,"postHttps accpet");


  HMAC_CTX ctx;
  HMAC_CTX_init(&ctx);
  HMAC_Init_ex(&ctx, AUTH_KEY, strlen(AUTH_KEY), EVP_sha256(), NULL);
  HMAC_Update(&ctx, (unsigned char*)&szJsonData, strlen(szJsonData));
  HMAC_Final(&ctx, result, &len);
  HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i != len; i++){
      int length = strlen(sign);
      char *s = sign;
      sprintf(s + length, "%02x", (unsigned int)result[i]);
  }

  free(result);

  string auth_head = "Authorization:";
  auth_head += UrlEncode(sign).c_str();

  log(Info,"postHttps requetContent %s auth_head %s size %u len %u", requetContent.str().c_str(),auth_head.c_str(),requetContent.str().size(),strlen(szJsonData));

  try 
  {
      CURL *pCurl = NULL;
      CURLcode res;

      pCurl = curl_easy_init();
      if (NULL != pCurl) 
      {
          curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);

          curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.xxxx.com/id");
          curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
          curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
          curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
          curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
          //curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
          //curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
          curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
          struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;

          log(Info,"httpsPost before apped headers");

          headers = curl_slist_append(headers, auth_head.c_str());
          headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: text/plain");
          headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "charset:utf-8");
          headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");

          curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
          curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
          curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, on_writebuff); 
          curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, bodyBuff);
          curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, header_handler);    
          curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, headBuff);

          curl_easy_setopt(pCurl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, requetContent.str().c_str());
          curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE,requetContent.str().size()); 

          int HTTP_flag = 0;
          curl_easy_getinfo(pCurl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &HTTP_flag); 
          res = curl_easy_perform(pCurl);
          log(Info,"httpsPost after curl_easy_perform");

          curl_slist_free_all(headers);
          curl_easy_cleanup(pCurl);


          if (res == CURLE_OK) 
          {
              std::string httpRes = headBuff;


              HttpParser::ParseResponseHead(httpRes,headResult);

              std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator it = headResult.find("HTTP");
              if(it != headResult.end())
              {
                  std::string& value = it->second;
                  if(value != "200 OK")
                  {
                      log(Error,"postHttps HTTP %s", value.c_str());
                  }
                  else 
                  {

                      json_char* json = (json_char*)bodyBuff;
                      json_value* value = json_parse(json,strlen(bodyBuff));

                      process_value(value, 0,bodyResult);
                      json_value_free(value);

                      log(Info,"httpsPost headMap %d bodyMap %d", headResult.size(),bodyResult.size());

                  }
              }

          }
          else 
          {
              log(Info,"curl_easy_perform() failed:%s", curl_easy_strerror(res));
          }



      }

  }
  catch (std::exception &ex)
  {
      log(Info,"curl exception %s", ex.what());
  }

  log(Info,"httpPost uid %u elapse %u", uid,ssend-start);
  ```

  }

Comment: valgrind is your friend, or simply single-step in gdb until it goes boom

Comment: crash in 'curl_easy_perform ',so valgrind no help.I have find another way to generate hmac,it works.

Answer (score 0):

use ssl,you should init some thinds. like below

```
void Callbackfee::init_locks(void)
{
    int i;

    if(m_lockarray == NULL)
    {
        m_lockarray = (pthread_mutex_t *)OPENSSL_malloc(CRYPTO_num_locks() *
                                                    sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
    }
    if(m_lockarray != NULL)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < CRYPTO_num_locks(); ++i) {
            pthread_mutex_init(&(m_lockarray[i]), NULL);
        }
        CRYPTO_set_id_callback(&thread_id);
        CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(&lock_callback);
    }
}
```